# Why does setInterval() give a circular reference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror, circular-reference, stringify

Considering the following code:

```
let id = setInterval(function f() {console.log("Nice.");}, 1000);
console.log(id);
JSON.stringify(id);
```

This ends in an error on the last line saying `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

The `console.log(id)` gives

```
Timeout {
  _called: false,
  _idleTimeout: 1000,
  _idlePrev: 
   TimersList {
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     _timer: Timer { '0': [Function: listOnTimeout], _list: [Circular] },
     _unrefed: false,
     msecs: 1000,
     nextTick: false },
  _idleNext: 
   TimersList {
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     _timer: Timer { '0': [Function: listOnTimeout], _list: [Circular] },
     _unrefed: false,
     msecs: 1000,
     nextTick: false },
  _idleStart: 81,
  _onTimeout: [Function: f],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: 1000,
  _destroyed: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6,
  [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 1 }
```

Why does the Timeout object contain a circular reference?

Comment: Why are you JSON.stringifying it?

Answer (score 4):

Please note, that [`setInterval`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args) in node.js behaves differently than [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) in javascript. While the javascript version returns an integer, node.js [returns a Timeout object.](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout) and is not intended for serialization.

Answer (score 1):

The [Timeout object](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout) contains a reference to itself (which can be accessed with [`id.ref()`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_ref))

You can actually see it in the `console.log()` output:

```
TimersList {
  _idleNext: [Circular],
  _idlePrev: [Circular],
  _timer: Timer { '0': [Function: listOnTimeout], _list: [Circular] },
  _unrefed: false,
   msecs: 1000,
   nextTick: false },
_idleNext:
```

You can't serialize it using `JSON.stringify()` because the object contains a reference to itself, and that object also contains a reference to itself, and that object also contains a reference to itself (see where I'm going here?)

Comment: Yes, I saw the `Circular` in there. My main question is; why?

Comment: @kramer65 I've updated my question. Basically it's impossible to serialize any object that contains a reference to itself

Comment: I understand that, but my question was more: why does it contain a reference to itself? Whats the reason for that circular reference?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "serialize" your timeout object, you could use a helper class like below. This will serialize the timeouts by storing them in the internal `TimeoutHelper.timeouts` field, and return an ID, which you can later call with `TimeoutHelper.clearTimeout(i)`:

```js
let TimeoutHelper = (() => {
  let helper = {};
  let counter = 0;
  let timeouts = {};
  
  helper.setInterval = (fn, ms) => {
    let currCounter = counter++;
    
    timeouts[currCounter] = window.setInterval(fn, ms);
    
    return currCounter;
  }
  
  helper.clearTimeout = (id) => {
    if (typeof timeouts[id] === 'undefined') {
      return; // Mimic window.clearTimeout, and silently return if the ID doesn't exist
    }
    window.clearInterval(timeouts[id]);
    delete timeouts[id];
  }
  
  return helper;
})();

var i = TimeoutHelper.setInterval(() => console.log('test'), 1000);

console.log(`Serialized TimeoutHelper id: ${i}`);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`Clearing Timeout: ${i}`);
  TimeoutHelper.clearTimeout(i);
}, 5000);
```