# What is Symbol(asyncId) and can you use it to clear intervals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, serialization, settimeout

I'm working with `setInterval()` in NodeJS and saw that it returned a Timeout object that contained some information, one of which was `Symbol(asyncId)`.

What is `Symbol(asyncId)` and is it possible to use this as a reference to an interval to `clearInterval()`? If so, how?

This is my current code:

```js
interval = setInterval(async function () {
    prepareObj(message);
    console.log(interval);
    const intervalID = Reflect.ownKeys(interval).find(
      (key) => key.toString() === "Symbol(asyncId)"
    );
    await saveID(message, interval[intervalID]);
  }, 5000);
```

`setInterval()` is being run multiple times and I need another way of clearing each individual interval, since `interval` will get reassigned to contain the newest `Timeout` object. I've attempted to store the value of `Symbol(asyncId)` in an SQLite DB, to later access this value to clear the interval without success.

**Attempt with Map**

```js
let intervals = new Map();
interval = setInterval(async function () {
    prepareCard(message);
    console.log(interval);
    await saveID(message, interval);
  }, 5000);

async function saveID(message, id) {
  intervals.set(`${message.channel.id}`, { interval });
}

// Clearing interval
const objToClear = intervals.get(channel);
console.log(objToClear);
const clear = clearInterval(objToClear["interval"]);
console.log(clear);
```

When calling `clearTimeout()`, I only clear the most recent set interval and not the targeted interval.

Comment: Yes, whatever setInterval returns you use with clearInterval.

Comment: @Keith How would you go about using ``Symbol(asyncId)`` to clear an interval?

Comment: Given that [it's not documented](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout), I would strictly advise against it. Why do you need another reference than just the `Timeout` object?

Comment: I'm dealing with the same ``setInterval()`` being run multiple times, so would need an alternative way of clearing the timeout other than using the variable containing the Timeout object.

Comment: I'm not sure what browser your using, but the return value is normally a numeric value,  Symbols are a unique identifier, to get the value of one you need the original Symbol. We maybe need more context here.

Comment: He's using node.js, not a browser, where it is indeed an object. But the usage pattern is exactly the same.

Comment: You need to store all of the return values from `setInterval` and call `clearInterval` for each of them.

Comment: I've updated the question with a bit of backstory and the current code I have.

Comment: Oh, never noticed the node tag.  So if node is returning a Symbol, even if you create multiple symbols with the same name, there still  unique.  `Symbol(ABC) != Symbol(ABC)`

Comment: Oh I see, are these Symbols the unique identifier of each interval?

Comment: So you need to save the various return values from `setInterval` and call `clearInterval` individually on each of them.

Comment: I'm using an SQLite DB for storage, I'm not sure I can store entire objects in the DB. Is there any alternative approach here?

Comment: If your trying to serialise the return value, you can't do this directly.  But what you could do is store the returned symbols inside a map that store a an incrementing reference, you could then serialise this, and use the map to de-serialize later..

Comment: @Californium Ah, you want to store references to them in a database - that's important info missing from the question. But yeah, I'd recommend keeping your own ids in a `Map` like Keith suggested, and not use the symbols at all.

Comment: I see, so basically store the entire return object in a map, and store a reference to them in my DB. That way I can access the reference when I want to clear it, and grab the right Timeout object, right? (I've also updated my post with some more information)

Comment: Check out this answer. I think they're doing what you want to do. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51526843/1495198

Comment: @Californium Exactly, yes

Comment: @Bergi I've tried an approach but it only clears the latest set interval. I've updated my post to reflect my new code.

Comment: @Californium Are there multiple intervals per channel? It's not exactly clear in what contexts these snippets run. You should only need to insert the `interval` in your map when creating it, not every time you save a message.

Comment: @Bergi That seemed to be the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is `Symbol(asyncId)`

It's an [internal symbol used in the timer implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/ca46c3b5dc7d349274c720345a48c5e862b66969/lib/internal/timers.js#L103-L105) of node.js to realise [async hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) on timers.

> …and can you use it to clear intervals?

No. <s>There's no lookup table afaics, and even if there was you shouldn't mess with it.</s> See below.

> I need to store a value in an SQLite DB, to later access this value to clear the interval.

You can come up with your own ids for that:

```
import * as timers from 'timers';

let counter = 0;
const intervals = new Map();

export function setInterval(callback, delay, ...args) {
  const timer = timers.setInterval(callback, delay, ...args);
  timeouts.set(++counter, timer);
  return counter;
}
export function clearInterval(id) {
  const timer = intervals.get(id);
  timers.clearInterval(timer);
  return intervals.delete(id);
}
```

However, I just noticed that there is a [recent commit](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/ca46c3b5dc7d349274c720345a48c5e862b66969) (June 2020) that allows `Timer` instances to be used as keys in objects, providing a way to coerce them to numbers:

```
const timer = setInterval(…);
const id = Number(timer);
…
clearInterval(id);
```

Not sure when this will be released :-)

A general word of caution: timer ids are not globally unique, but only per thread and execution of your program. For storing them in an external database, that means you will have to remove all ids at startup of your application, they're dangling otherwise. Ideally this would never happen for a clean shutdown where all timers are cleared and references from the database to them are deleted, but you can never be certain. To alleviate the problem, you might also prefix the ids stored in the database with a db connection id or something else that's stored in the database and will be incremented on each startup.

Comment: This solution and the solution Keith provided proved to be the best in this case. Kudos to everyone who helped out!

Answer (score -1):

```js
// this will print "hi" to your console every second
const myIntervalId = setInterval(() => console.log("hi"), 1000);

// this will stop the "hi" from being printed 
clearInterval(myIntervalId)
```

Fun fact... `setTimeout` also returns an id, and shares the same id namespace as `setInterval`, so you can clear an id from `setTimeout` with `clearInterval`!

Comment: Yes, I understand that you can set the interval as a variable and clear it that way. But is it possible to clear it using some other way, i.e. using the value of ``Symbol(asyncId)``?

Comment: `myIntervalId` is not an id, it's an object.

Comment: @Bergi If I recall correctly some early versions of javascript returned an integer. I used to pass numbers that just "looked" like the numerical value of the thing returned by setInterval to clear the timer and it worked. Not sure how far back it goes but today is the first time I learned of setInterval returning a Timeout object

Comment: Yeah, new to me too. But the semantics are the same regardless. You can treat them like an id.

Comment: @slebetman That's how it works in the DOM, but node.js does (afaik since ever) use timer objects.